# Angular: TextArea show different rows different character count

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

Angular: **TextArea** is defined under the table as 5th column, now implemented changes to include character count, Count is visible **but for all rows only the 1st row count** is showing.

For example say 1st row Textarea count is 23, then for all rows **irrespective of data present in that TextArea, count is showing 23 for all rows**.

Plus when i am editing 1st row then all rows count is changing..

Hence how to make **different row show count specific to that row TextArea**

Below is the code implemented by me

HTML

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
  <td>
    <div class="textarea-wrapper">
      <textarea pInputTextArea [(ngModel)]="rowData.value" (ngModelChange)="valueChange(rowData.value)"
        maxlength="1000">
   </textarea>
      <span class="remaning">{{remainingText}}</span>
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-template>
```

.ts

```
 valueChange(value) {
    this.remainingText = 1000 - value;
 }
```

CSS:

```
.textarea-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.remaning {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

I am using Angular primeNG table exactly like below
[Angular 6 PrimeNG - how to add a checkbox with distinct values from one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633982/angular-6-primeng-how-to-add-a-checkbox-with-distinct-values-from-one-column)

Comment: does your textarea have the same ngModel for all the rows?

Comment: `this.remainingText` is the same value for all the rows?

Comment: Yes ngModel is same for all the rows
@Redan

Comment: Yes this.remainingText is same for all the rows @Jotan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are assigning a global variable to all rows, instead of specific one for each row. On the `[(ngModel)]="value"` you should assign the rowData count, like `[(ngModel)]="rowData[value]"` where `rowData`is your current row.

Your html has to be like this:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
  <td>
   <div class="textarea-wrapper">
    <textarea pInputTextArea [(ngModel)]="rowData.value" 
     (ngModelChange)="valueChange(value,rowData)" maxlength="1000">        
    </textarea>
    <span class="remaning">{{rowData.remainingText}}</span>
  </div>
</td>
```

`rowData.value` is your textArea value, I don't know which attribute do you use.

On your `.ts`:

```
valueChange(value,rowData) {
    rowData.remainingText = rowData.remainingText || 1000; // remainingText is the value from your textarea, and rowData the whole object
    rowData.remainingText = 1000 - rowData.remainingText.length;
 }
```

Comment: actually i am getting all the data from server, say there are 5 rows so data for 5 having same variable name: Currency

Comment: you mean to say i need to replace `[(ngModel)]="value"` with 
`[(ngModel)]="rowData[value]"`  ??

Comment: Could you please paste your `html table` ? You have to assign on the `[(ngModule)] ` the rowData

Comment: i am using primgNg table exactly like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633982/angular-6-primeng-how-to-add-a-checkbox-with-distinct-values-from-one-column

Comment: I edited the question, try it and get the result, or at least get the workaround :)

Comment: rowData should be initialized also i guess, because implementing above changes remainingText is not getting displayed

Comment: actually console.log(value) is giving current rowValue which i am editing

Comment: Get the value from rowValue you want to compare with. Example: `1000 - rowValue.textArea.length - 1000 // textArea.length has to be the string from the textArea`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203128/discussion-between-angelina-and-jotan).

Comment: Marking as answer, since it worked for me, thanks @Jotan

Comment: Hi @Jotan, please help me on this

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435846/angular-get-row-data-present-just-below-the-row-that-has-been-edited